# construct class from variable with namespace

Tags: php

The class I want to contruct has a namespace,example:`\class_name`.

So now I'm wondering how I can construct that class in PHP.

---

### I have tried:

```
$class_name = 'class_name';
new \$class_name();
```

### but i receive an error:

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '$class_name' (T_VARIABLE)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `$class_name = '\class_name';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the full class name in your variable as stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php):

> One must use the fully qualified name (class name with namespace prefix). Note that because there is no difference between a qualified and a fully qualified Name inside a dynamic class name, function name, or constant name, the leading backslash is not necessary.

So do it like this:

```
$class_name = '\class_name';
new $class_name();
```